# Pimcore specific user roles

Tags: pimcore

I'm testing Pimcore right now, to see if it's a good fit for our company.

I was wondering if there is a way to give a user specific rights, like an author only being able to make content and edit his own content?

Comment: Of course. You should check this article:
https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Administration_of_Pimcore/Users_and_Roles.html
Especially **Element Permissions - Workspaces**

You could be also interested in connecting permissions with workflow:
https://www.gatherdigital.co.uk/community/post/pimcore-workflow-management-pt1/66

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can provide user or role based permission to documents, assets or objects.  Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmYuR.png) to see the screenshot of the user screen

Steps are as follows -

1. Go to settings -> User
2. Click on the specific user on which you want add some permissions.
3. On the right screen part go to the workflow tab.
4. Click on the add button present near Document title if you want to add permissions on documents. Same can be done on Assets and on Objects
5. Drag and drop documents on which you want to allow permissions.
6. Check the boxes if you want to allow user to publish, unpublish, delete etc.
7. Save

Same can be done on roles as well. If you want same set of permissions on couple of users then you can make a specific role, assign the desired permissions and then assign that role to multiple users.